# Conics involving a curve in the form of $Ax^2+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$

Tags: calculus

Recall that a curve of the form $Ax^2+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ is a parabola, ellipse, hyperbola, line, or 2 lines. Show that given any 4 points in the plane, there is such a curve that contains them.

Comment: Actually, 5 points. How are you trying to do this? It is not a calculus problem ;)

Comment: Or one single point, or the empty set. Try $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=0$ and $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=-1$, respectively. They are not really "curves", but they are possible sets of solutions.

Comment: Ah, I missed the absence of the $xy$ term. $4$ points it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Take the four points $(x_1,y_1)$, ..., $(x_4, y_4)$.

If you replaces this points in main equation you have $A x_k^2+B y_k^2+D x_k +E y_k +F = 0$, for $k=1,2,3$ and $4$.

In this case you have four linear equations for five variables $(A,B,C,D,E,F)$, you can solve this equations with linear algebra,...

Comment: I'm confused still on how you would solve this using linear algebra... could you please explain further?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, the poser of the question posits four points and the template of a quadratic expression in x and y which has no xy term and which is to be equated to 0. The absence of the xy term means that the axes of the locus are not to be oblique to the coördinate axes, and further that the locus can indeed be uniquely determined by the four points, so long as no two of the points are concurrent. Given the four points
$(x_1|y_1)$, $(x_2|y_2)$, $(x_3|y_3)$, $(x_4|y_4)$, the required equation will be
$\begin{vmatrix}
x^2  &y^2 &x  &y  &1\\
x_1^2 &y_1^2 &x_1 &y_1 &1\\
x_2^2 &y_2^2 &x_2 &y_2 &1\\
x_3^2 &y_3^2 &x_3 &y_3 &1\\
x_4^2 &y_4^2 &x_4 &y_4 &1\\
\end{vmatrix}=0$.

Comment: Hey, would somebody do me the favor of editing the second answer (mine) so that the exes and wyes have subscripts instead of appended numerals AND set up a determinant (5×5) for the 25 elements that I have strung out? I don't know yet how to use the Mathjax editor. Thanks.